# I want to open three different activity when I login with their respective roles from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[image]

I have three roles in my firebase database

1. teacher
2. Student
3. coordinator.

In that, if I log in with teacher then it should check role from the database and open teacher activity. Same for student and coordinator.

** Code:**

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login_Form.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Form.this, Adminpage.class);
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                } else {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed Or User Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You can try with storing users id with field role,

Comment: You may be interested in this article:
https://medium.com/better-programming/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4

Comment: show us your code and things which you have acheived so far !

Comment: i have tried with Firebase authentication, then its working for single role. But I need the same for 3 diffrent role

Comment: consider post your firebase structure as well.

Comment: database image added in description

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this one

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login_Form.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Form.this, Adminpage.class);
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                } else {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed Or User Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
```

Comment: this is not an answer. Please edit your post instead .

Answer (score 0):

While login , you must be using either phone number or email Id . 
If so , then you can fetch the result using the entered email id .

```
 postRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    val userData: HashMap<String, User> = dataSnapshot.value as HashMap<String, User>
                    var  userId :String = ""

                    userData.keys.forEach {  userId =it}
                    Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity,"Welcome Back . Happy to see you again" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    startHomeActivity()
                } 
            }
        })
```

In above , i have check if the email is present in the firebase database or not . Once it get success,  then we have dataSnapshot in which you will get complete data associated with that email id .There you can check if its teacher , student etc. 
 There is a check if dataSnapshot is empty or not just to ensure your dataSnapshot is having user data.

```
                val userData: HashMap<String, User> = dataSnapshot.value as HashMap<String, User>
```

This will give you the entire data of your entry .